# ajax=>perl-cgi issue with semicolon

Tags: ajax, perl

hello
I have a simple html form and standard ajax code which is supposed to send form data to a cgi script (ajax) but looks like if my form has a semicolon(;) in data then cgi code truncates everything after semicolon (for that field)..

please advise

Comment: vanilla ajax and a perl CGI program is not enough for *anybody* to help you. Is one end expecting *JSON* --if it is a bare semi-colon is flat out *invalid*.

Comment: Possible problem(?); a semi-colon is a valid CGI param pair delimiter. So `?key=value;something` would leave `key` = `value` and a param of `something` with no value.

Answer (score 1):

actually i was passing values to CGI using ajax like http.send('va11='+val1+'&val2='+val2);
where val1 is a blob having tons of text with semicolon... and perl CGI (receiver) ignored everything after 1st semicolon in val1.. issue was solved with using encodeURIComponent (function in JS).. thanks for your help